# Listing blobs in Loop not being Shown

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I've created a script which deletes blobs which are older than a set date, I'm trying to run this using an automation account, however when I test it using the "test pane" it gives the desired output, which is a list of blobs to be deleted, however when it actually runs using the automation account it doesn't display a list of blobs to be deleted.

The code is below:

```
### delete blobs older than 30 days 
param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [int32]$daysToKeep, 
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$storageAccount,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$storageContainer,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$storageAccessKey
)

    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"

        # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
        $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         
        "Logging in to Azure..."
        Add-AzureRmAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
         Write-Host "logged into Azure"        

$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount -StorageAccountKey $storageAccessKey 
New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $storageContainer -Context $context -Permission Blob -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$EGBlobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $storageContainer -Context $context | sort-object LastModified | select lastmodified, name
foreach($blob in $EGBlobs) 
{ 
    if($blob.lastmodified -lt (get-date).AddDays($daysToKeep*-1))
        {
        $blob_date = [datetime]$blob.LastModified.UtcDateTime
        Write-Output "-----------------------------------" 
        write-output "Purging blob from Storage: " $blob.name 
        write-output "----------------------------------- " 
        write-output "Last Modified Date of the Blob: " $blob_date 
        Write-Output "-----------------------------------" 
        Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $blob.name -Container $storageContainer -Context $context 

        } 
}
```

Can't see where I'm going wrong, is this a setting within Azure Automation account.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it is, but in fact it is.

Just move the line `Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $blob.name -Container $storageContainer -Context $context` to the top in the loop, it will work fine.

It should be:

```
foreach($blob in $EGBlobs) 
{ 
    if($blob.lastmodified -lt (get-date).AddDays(2))
        {
        Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $blob.name -Container $storageContainer -Context $context 
        $blob_date = [datetime]$blob.LastModified.UtcDateTime
        Write-Output "-----------------------------------" 
        write-output "Purging blob from Storage: " $blob.name 
        write-output "----------------------------------- " 
        write-output "Last Modified Date of the Blob: " $blob_date 
        Write-Output "-----------------------------------" 

        } 
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help, did you get that output using the test pane? I get the same output during the test pane, however when it actually runs it deletes the blobs but doesn't provide a list of blobs to be deleted. Confused..

Comment: @NorrinRad Yes, I get the same result of you. Follow my answer and do that in publish, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it with your changes :)